# EntityHydrate task failed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I recently installed the Visual Studio 11 Beta alongside Visual Studio 2010. After that I was unable to build my projects in Visual Studio 2010 that rely on PostSharp so I uninstalled Visual Studio 11 and the .Net Framework 4.5 Beta.

When I now try to build my projects in Visual Studio 2010 I get the following error:

```
Error   20: The "EntityHydrate" task failed unexpectedly.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.SchemaManager' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityFrameworkVersions.Version3'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.SchemaManager..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.SchemaManager.GetSchemaVersion(XNamespace xNamespace)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Integration.Build.EntityHydrate.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)   
BuildingModule
```

I already reinstalled Entity Framework 4.1 and .Net Framework 4 without success. I also was unable to find information about the purpose of the "EntityHydrate" task or why it tries to access the "Version3" namespace of entity framework.

Any idea how to fix this? I couldn't find a download link to Entity Framework 3, maybe that could solve the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks for raising this. We (the EF team) did some investigation and we concluded that the issue could be triggered in a machine that contains SQL Server 11 and Visual Studio 11 Beta.

In the beta, the setup of the EF Tools (also known as "SQL Server Data Framework Tools") contains this MSBUILD targets file:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSbuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.Targets\ImportAfter\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Integration.targets**

Note: Use “Program Files” without “(x86)” if you have the 32 bits version of Windows.

This file is a stale remnant of the integration between the Entity Framework Designer and SQL Server Data Tools, which was contained in the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview but removed in the beta (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/03/09/ef-integration-removed-from-sql-server-data-tools.aspx) for more details). The file has been removed in more recent internal builds, so it won't be present in RTM.

You might be able to work around this problem you can remove or rename the targets file, e.g. adding the .backup extension to it.

**EDIT: Scratch that... Someone reports below that renaming is not sufficient. You have to remove the file.**

The other workaround suggested in this thread will also work but it has the big disadvantage of removing the whole Entity Framework Designer from your Visual Studio setup.

Comment: Ok, we'll investigate more. Can you confirm that you had installed the VS 11 developer preview before updating to beta? Also, have you installed any other previews, e.g. SQL Server?

Comment: No previews were installed, only VS2010 RTM SP1 and SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM. After uninstalling data" thingies as @spinut suggested, it is working.

Comment: For all those struggling, it's not enough to rename the file. I needed to actually delete it (move it to a different folder) for it to start working (after removing *EVERYTHING* I possibly could from the system). Then, it started to work.

Comment: Renaming file did not work. Moving it out of the folder did work.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me by removing the file from the folder. Thanks

Comment: +1 just for reminding me to use the x86 version of the command line rather than the x64 version...

Answer (score 21):

I finally figured it out. The problem is caused by Entity Framework 5 that is installed with .Net Framework 4.5 Beta. EF 5 is referenced by the Version3 constant that is mentioned in the error message. The internal name of EF 4 is Version2.

The "Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.SchemaManager" class is part of a component called *SQL Server Data Framework Tools* which is installed with Visual Studio 11. Even after I had uninstalled all Visual Studio 11 and .Net Framework 4.5 related stuff this component was still there and used by VS 2010 for projects that make use of the Entity Framework.

After I removed that component everything is working again. There might be more than one entry for this in the list of installed programs, just search for "data" to find them.

Comment: Excellent! thanks for your work figuring this one out. I had the same problem (along with async ctp for silverlight), and this was a major piece of the puzzle in getting Visual Studio 2010 back to its original state.

Comment: I had the same problem but I could not uninstall SQL Server Data Framework Tools.  It gives me the error "Visual Studio product directory is not found".  I cleaned my registry with CCCleaner after I uninstalled VS11 so maybe that did caused this error.  However, I did uninstall every other SQL 2012 in my Programs and Features and it did still seem to fix the error for me.  Thank you.

Comment: I had the same issue Scott. I otherwise uninstalled anything that was related to those though and it fixed it.

Comment: This workaround has the disadvantage of disabling the Entity Framework Designer in VS 11. If you want to preserve this functionality, you can try the workaround I explained below, which consists of renaming an msbuild .targets file.

Comment: this is a band-aid and not the fix / correct answer, @divega has answered this correctly below, you should really change the check mark to save others time and headaches

Answer (score 6):

you must delete this directory **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSbuild\4.0**

Comment: I had uninstall errors (Visual Studio directory not found) and this suggestions actually fixed my problem.

Comment: This is a little overkill and causes other issues, the other solutions to remove the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Integration.targets file will fix the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend either removing or renaming the directory. This directory can be used by other tools that need to integrate with MSBUILD, so you could break something else. Just remove the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Integration.targets file as I recommended from inside the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only posting because nothing here seemed to work. Based on what @divega said, I decided to go in and remove all SQL Server 2012 entries from 'Programs and Features', after which I could build my entity models in VS2010.