# Encountered an error hydrating the EDMX file?

Tags: entity-framework-4.3, visual-studio-2012

I just got the Visual Studio 2012 RC Ultimate and I'm trying to connect to a database using EntityFramework Database First. I've created the EDMX file like I've done a thousand times and when I build my project I get 2 errors. I'm not sure if they are related or not.

> Encountered an error hydrating the EDMX file 'Model.edmx'.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've spent several hours on Google trying to see if anyone else has had this issue and I'm not finding anything at all.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746923/entity-framework-bug-after-migrating-a-sharepoint-project-from-2010-to-2012-rc same question here

Comment: thanks, hopefully this gets resolved soon.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554626/entityhydrate-task-failed/9986445.

Comment: Thanks divega. That worked perfectly, I saw that post but I wasn't sure if it was the same exact issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. close all instances of Visual Studio
2. delete the file **`C:\Program Files
   (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfterMicrosoft.Data.Tools.Integration.targets`**
3. restart Visual Studio & rebuild solution

i hope this saves someone a lot of trouble like it could have for me -ck

**update:**

apparently this is only an issue if you installed VS2012RC over the top of VS2012 Developer Preview, as something was removed / renamed and that file remains from the old install and wreaks havoc...

Comment: I also get the same error in VS2010. Luckily it was on my home computer and my home projects aren't super critical. I'll probably mark this as an answer after I try it. But hopefully there will just be a fix for VS2012 soon.

Comment: apparently this is only an issue if you installed VS2012RC over the top of VS2012 Developer Preview, as something was removed / renamed and that file remains from the old install and wreaks havoc....

Comment: @ckozl agreed. this is my case.

Comment: Very useful.  This saved an unquantifiable amount of time - 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Big thanks to divega about pointing me in the right direction with his answer on this post

[EntityHydrate task failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554626/entityhydrate-task-failed/9986445)

Look for his answer there, just simply remove this file and everything works perfectly

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSbuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.Targets\ImportAfter\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Integration.targets

Comment: i hate to be a wiener, but i did give you that same answer to your own question, discovered independently, on this thread, 7 hours before you posted this, what gives?

Answer (score 1):

FIY

Renaming the file does not work.

Deleting it solved my problem.

One more thing: The problem occured on my 32bit W7 box only. On my 64bit W7 box everything works fine

Big thanks for the quick answer, I can continue working again.

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to identify an exact repro for this issue in case this helps us getting a fix in the setup of Visual Studio 2012 RTM. I need information about the exact configurations and sequence of installation of preview and beta software previous to RC from someone that was able to repro this.

Comment: I have detailed notes on my installation steps. Where can I send them?  tom.allen<at>cricketsoft.com

Comment: Also, what tools should I use to capture the system configuration for you?